# Conditional pattern matching in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml, racket

Since all the examples in the guide are with lists, I find it difficult to see how to use pattern matching in Racket to write conditional matching like OCaml does, for example:

```
read ~var_a var_b s = match s.[0] with
    | _ when var_b >= var_a + 4 ->
        (* Do something *)
    | "a" when is_negative var_b -> 
        (* Do something else *)
    ...
```

How would I write something similar in Racket?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`racket/match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) library includes pattern matching that can use arbitrary predicates through the `?` pattern.  Along with `and`, you should be able to get Racket's matcher to behave.  Although I'm a little weak in my OCaml, I think the following translation of the code above matches its meaning:

```
(define (my-read #:var-a var-a var-b s)
  (match (string-ref s 0)
    [(and _
          (? (lambda (_)
               (>= var-b (+ var-a 4)))))
     "do something"]
    [(and '#\a
          (? (lambda (_)
               (< var-b 0))))
     "do something else"]))

;; Exercising the first case:     
(my-read #:var-a 50
         60 "blah")

;; Exercising the second case:
(my-read #:var-a 50
         -40 "alphabet")
```

The `?` matcher has an implicit `and` embedded within it, so the code can be expressed slightly more succinctly as:

```
(define (my-read #:var-a var-a var-b s) 
  (match (string-ref s 0)
    [(? (lambda (_)
          (>= var-b (+ var-a 4))))
     "do something"]
    [(? (lambda (_)
          (< var-b 0))
        #\a)
     "do something else"]))
```

In both, the lambdas in there aren't watching what got matched, so I just named them `_` to denote a don't-care.  But you can imagine more sophisticated patterns where the predicates could care deeply about what exactly got matched.

Eli suggests using a general `cond` here, since there isn't any significant pattern matching in the code.  I agree.  The code would look like this:

```
(define (my-read #:var-a var-a var-b s) 
  (cond
    [(>= var-b (+ var-a 4))
     "do something"]
    [(and (char=? (string-ref s 0) #\a)
          (< var-b 0))
     "do something else"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Pattern-matching can easily be translated into a sequence of tests, there is no language where you cannot do that.

What's great with OCaml (and probably Haskell) pattern-matching is that the compiler translates the code into the optimal sequence of tests when it is possible (i.e. the program will never test twice the same condition, at least when you avoid the `when` guards).

Comment: I would expect that the same happens in Racket, since it has explicit pattern matching capablities, no?

Comment: It's probably the case if you use `match`, but not if you use `cond`. But I am no expert in Racket, only in OCaml.